# How to put % or any other in RewriteRule in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, rule

Well, I have that rewrite rule in my .htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/?([a-zA-Z0-9+_-]+)?,?((\d+))?/?((\d+))?/?$ index.php?page=$1&id=$2&cat=$3&view=$5 [QSA,L]
```

so if i have page like this: /search/search+word,5/2 theres no problem...

but if I have page like this: `/search/%EA%EE%F2%EA%E8,5/2` theres a problem. I can't use cyrillic words for my search form. I try to put % or \% or ^% in the RewriteRule but without luck :( I try with few more symbols and than replace it with % in the index but again doesn't work.

Can someone tell me how to me this RewriteRule to work with % too? (Or with another symbol that I can use)

**EDIT:**

with this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/?([^,]+)?,?((\d+))?/?((\d+))?/?$ index.php?page=$1&id=$2&cat=$3&view=$5 [QSA,L,B]
```

The answers are that:

```
sitename.com/ -> Page:index; ID:.php; CAT:; VIEW:; <- ERROR: must be page="" and ID=""

sitename.com/home/ -> Page:home; ID:; CAT:; VIEW:;

sitename.com/video/152 -> Page:video; ID:152; CAT:; VIEW:;

sitename.com/video/0/3/ -> Page:video; ID:0/3; CAT:; VIEW:; <- ERROR: must be VIEW=3

sitename.com/search/ -> Page:search; ID:; CAT:; VIEW:;

sitename.com/search/search+word/ -> Page:search; ID:search+word/; CAT:; VIEW:; <- Its OK... but still don't want this / in the id query

sitename.com/search/search+word,2/ -> Page:search; ID:search+word; CAT:2; VIEW:;

sitename.com/search/search+word,2/3/ -> Page:search; ID:search+word; CAT:2; VIEW:3;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
## If the request is for a valid file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
## If the request is for a valid link
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l
## don't do anything
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/([^,]+),(\d+)/(\d+)/?$ index.php?page=$1&id=$2&cat=$3&view=$4 [NC,QSA,L,B]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/([^,/]+)/(\d+)/?$ index.php?page=$1&id=$2&view=$3 [NC,QSA,L,B]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/([^,/]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1&id=$2 [NC,QSA,L,B]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [NC,QSA,L,B]
```

Comment: Nope... it still doesn't work :/

Not Found
The requested URL /search/êîòêè,2/3/ was not found on this server.

Comment: Try this: `RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/([^,]+),(\d+)/(\d+)/?$ index.php?page=$1&id=$2&cat=$3&view=$4 [QSA,L,B]`

Comment: Man... this isn't working! now i see that if i haven't got /page/id/2 and the page stop working ...

Comment: sitename.com/
sitename.com/video/5
sitename.com/search/
it work only for:
sitename.com/search/search+word,2/3/

However... i edit ti with ? into this
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/?([^,]+)?,?((\d+))?/?((\d+))?/?$ index.php?page=$1&id=$2&cat=$3&view=$5 [QSA,L,B]
but i still have problems in index 
when I'm in index it send index to page and .php to id..

Comment: I try... but isn't working... I really don't know nothing about RewriteRules... I try ?(^[a-zA-Z0-9+_-]+)? or ?([^,][a-zA-Z0-9+_-]+)? or ?([a-zA-Z0-9+_-]+[^,])? or ?([a-zA-Z0-9+_-^,]+)?  or ?([a-zA-Z0-9+_-^]+)? or ?([^,a-zA-Z0-9+_-]+)? etc... but nothing works :(

Comment: No don't use all those `?` as you earlier had. Above will work for both `/video/5` and `/search` URIs

Comment: well..  yeah.. that is what i want :) multiple work for all pages

Comment: With that that i edit it yes... but not the / page (the index)

Comment: You mean `http://domain.com/` doesn't work? Try to provide all the details otherwise it is difficult to help

Comment: sn.com/ -> Page:index; ID:.php; CAT:; VIEW:; <- ERR: must be page="" and ID="" | sn.com/home/ -> Page:home; ID:; CAT:; VIEW:; | sn.com/video/152 -> Page:video; ID:152; CAT:; VIEW:; | sn.com/video/0/3/ -> Page:video; ID:0/3; CAT:; VIEW:; <- ERR: must be VIEW=3 | sn.com/search/ -> Page:search; ID:; CAT:; VIEW:; | sn.com/search/search+word/ -> Page:search; ID:search+word/; CAT:; VIEW:; <- Its OK... but still don't want this / in the id query | sn.com/search/search+word,2/ -> Page:search; ID:search+word; CAT:2; VIEW:; | sn.com/search/search+word,2/3/ -> Page:search; ID:search+word; CAT:2; VIEW:3;

Comment: If you try reading that comment can you read it :) Better to edit your question post all relevant details there.

Comment: PS: sorry about that... this site remove my new lines :(

Comment: Problem again: /news/0/2 -> [Page:404; ID:; CAT:; VIEW:;] <- Error 404: It must be VIEW=2 ||||||| /search/search+word/3/ -> [Page:404; ID:; CAT:; VIEW:;] <- Error 404: It must be id=search+word and View=3 without chosen category |||| Everything else is ok

Comment: 1st: RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/([^,]+),(\d+)?/?(\d+)?/?$ index.php?page=$1&id=$2&cat=$3&view=$4 [NC,QSA,L,B]
|||
3 "?" signs and its perfect :-) Thanks :)

Comment: CSS/JS is a very common problem actually. Just  just use absolute path in your css, js, images files rather than a relative one. Which means you have to make sure path of these files start either with `http://` or a slash `/`.
OR   You can try adding this in your page's HTML header: `<base href="/" />`

Comment: They are with / from when i use my RewriteRule in the first post. There they was fine... now not :(

Comment: Thank you a lot for you patience! Now its perfect :-)

Comment: Can you also upvote my answer also by clicking on triangle upward like I did for your question?